com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_OTHER (0xc0000466): Authentication failed for '' using com.hierynomus.smbj.auth.NtlmAuthenticator
trying to access Azure Netapps drive (Kind of network drive) using SMB protocol with smbj library.
It's working fine with user name and password (authendication). But getting following error while trying to accessing anonymously. How to address this issue?

com.hierynomus.mssmb2.SMBApiException: STATUS_OTHER (0xc0000466):
Authentication failed for '' using
com.hierynomus.smbj.auth.NtlmAuthenticator@2b98378d

My code is below,
SMBClient client = new SMBClient();
Connection connection = client.connect(SERVERNAME);
AuthenticationContext ac = AuthenticationContext.anonymous();                 
Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);
DiskShare share = (DiskShare)session.connectShare(SHARENAME);


I have a similar problem trying to access a shared folder on a windows box that's open for everyone ... AuthenticationContext.anonymous() doesn't work there also.
